# rnd:weighted-one-of-list work doesn't return the distribution I think it should

Tags: netlogo

I trying to use the rnd extension's function weighted-one-of-list.

My list looks like

```
observer>show female-yr-run-stats
```

`observer: [[117 0.001169] [118 0.002684] [119 0.004697] [120 0.003368] [121 0.004871] [122 0.018738] [123 0.034986] [124 0.070616] [125 0.035608] [126 0.012939] [127 0.011883] [128 0.016594] [129 0.068837] [130 0.044391] [131 0.028422] [132 0.053251] [133 0.023741] [134 0.042111] [135 0.035811] [136 0.022447] [137 0.031563] [138 0.024253] [139 0.030213] [140 0.024372] [141 0.033266] [142 0.059869] [143 0.028711] [144 0.030863] [145 0.04043] [146 0.008819] [147 0.012308] [148 0.008638] [149 0.021345] [150 0.016176] [151 0.009815] [152 0.017242] [153 0.014362] [154 0.010717] [155 0.015868] [156 0.003865] [157 0.008441] [158 0.004358] [159 0.003113] [160 0.002464] [161 0.001768]]`

The first item is day-of-the-year and the second is the probability (all sum to one).

I am using the code

```
  repeat 50000[
   let tempo first rnd:weighted-one-of-list female-yr-run-stats [ [p] -> last p ] 
        file-open "C://temp//check_wgt_random.csv"
         file-print (word tempo)
         file-close 
   ]
```

to randomly select a day-of-the-year 50000 times to check that the rnd:weighted-one-of-list function is doing what I want it to do. From the results, I get a distribution of day-of-the-year. But when I compare the resulting distribution to the original probability distribution, they are quite different.

I am thinking that the rnd:weighted-one-of-list with my list would be equivalent to randomly drawing from a multinomial distribution like R's rmultinom function. Am I correct? Am I doing something wrong?

Any help would be appreciated.

The graph below shows the comparisons

[image: Comparison of the original, EXCEL, R and netlogo distributions of day of the year]

Answer (score 0):

The `rnd:weighted-one-of-list` primitive works the way (I think) you think it works. From your data, it draws the value 112 with probability 3.04E-4, value 113 with probability 0.001236 etc. The probabilities don't have to add to 1 (I have assumed that you are correct that yours do). I can't see anything wrong with your use of this primitive for your draws.

But I am not sure about the file construction. You have the `file-open` and `file-close` inside the repeat so the file is opened, the new data is appended, the file is closed. It is not clear whether you ever clear the dataset. So perhaps the problem is that you have some data left over from when you were building your code. Do you get the same problem if you clear out all the old data and start again?

Comment: I delete the output file before the function is run; I neglected to show the code which is:  if file-exists? "C://temp//check_wgt_random.csv" [file-delete "C://temp//check_wgt_random.csv"].  I added a graph to my original post showing the comparison of the netlogo generated distribution of day of the year versus the original, EXCEL and R sample distributions.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to waste your time. I discovered what happened. I had two probabilities stream mixed up.